# Download a feature using Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

To integrate `JavaFX` into an existing RCP client I need to add the `fx.runtime` and `fx.target` features of the `e(fx)clipse project` to my IDE. I know that the usual way would be to download these by going to the `targetplatform -> add new software`, however I'd like to download these features and add them to a virtual P2 repository.
Is it possible to download a feature structure like in `http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/runtime-released/2.3.0/site/` with Maven in a single `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I was looking for:

```
eclipse -nosplash -verbose
 -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication
 -source Insert Source URL (e.g. http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.4milestones/)
 -destination Insert Destination URL (e.g. file:/tmp/3.4milestonesMirror/)
```

[More on this topic](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Repository_Mirroring)

Answer (score 0):

Search for it here : https://mvnrepository.com/.
Copy despondency and you are ready to go.

Comment: I did, the desired features are not listed there